# Make Dropdown Label smaller

Tags: android, spinner

I would like to figure out if it is possible to make Dropdown (Arrow) Logo of a Spinner smaller. 
See my two screenshots please:

[image: Would like to make that Dropdown Arrow Label smaller]

[image: I would basically like this to happen]

The first Screenshot shows that Dropdown label is pretty big.
The second shows what I really want to accomplish. It is not about the Dropdown, I want to have the ability to have more text when a item is already selected.

This is what I use as code:

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/heroSpinner"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"


                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="10sp"
                    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="15sp"

                    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
                    android:popupBackground="#8A8A8A"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

Can edit my mainActivity and Adapter if needed.

Can someone help me please? :)