# Android: Custom Spinner without selector

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner

i tried to **change the dropdownlabel / selector of a AndroidAppCombatSpinner**  before but did not really get useful help see: [Make Drowdown label smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52834891/make-dropdown-label-smaller).

So now I am wondering if it is possible to make a Spinner without a dropdown label.

**See the Screenshot for what I want to do:**

[image]

Edit: Added my XML file which is getting inflated:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/x_linearlayoutcontainer_inside"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSpinnerImage"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"

        android:src="@drawable/blue"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSpinnerText"

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"

        android:text="Accessory"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks guys for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

try to change the style of your spinner to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner" name="SpinnerwithNoArrow">
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/edit_text</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I am using a CustomSpinner which I inflate through an adapter. There to the best of my knowledge I do not use a a Resource file.

Comment: Do you have any idea? :/

Comment: you better use a Resource file to keep it simple

Comment: then you can use it in your view `<Spinner style="@style/SpinnerAsEditText" anyOtherAttributeYouNeed="..."></Spinner>`

Comment: but if you want somthing related to your example you might look at this link [https://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-spinner-examples.html]

Comment: I hope it will help you :)

Comment: hey the link does sadly not work. I want to use a Image and a Text in my Spinner thats why I need the customSpinner and therefore I should not use a resourcefile, (.. right? -> only layout and Adapter to inflate)